# use html code in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, hyperlink

Please tell me how i put html code in my iphone app

i have to show some Hyperlinks on my app

(Please don't suggest me to use UIButton)

please provide help or sample code for it if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432990/hyperlinks-within-about-text-for-iphone-application)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UIWebView. There are a number of tutorials available. Please google "UIWebView tutorial".